# Does Linux VFS cache a lookup if the file doesn't exists in the first time?

Tags: nginx, linux-kernel, vfs

I want to use Nginx `try_files` module in a scenario when most of the time the first argument doesn't exist and it would serve the second argument.

I wonder if VFS would cache the fact that the few files that I look up don't exist, and wouldn't issue reads to the disk for each of them.

Comment: The only disk read would be the directory, which gets cached like any other data.

Comment: As usual, caching affects only on performance, but not on the observed results. It is true that VFS caches a *negative lookup* (a lookup which returns "not exists" status). But proper filesystem will **invalidate** such cache when the file appears.